# C++ References Puzzle: My output appears reversed. Why?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

The output of the following code is "321" without quotes. Why not "123"?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int& inc(int& start)
{
 return ++start;
}

int main()
{
 int i = 0; 
 cout << inc(i) << inc(i) << inc(i) << endl;
}
```

Comment: The order in which subexpressions are evaluated is not specified in the C++ standard.

Comment: In this case it goes from right to left, debug it and you would see the calls !!

Answer (score 4):

Your code invokes Unspecified Behaviour because the order of evaluation of the 
arguments of `operator<<` is unspecified

Calls to `operator<<` modify the same variable. Don't write such code.

Note : Note that the code doesn't result in undefined behavior because there are sequence points (at least one function call) between when `i` is modified and when it is read'.

Comment: So does it or doesn't it invoke undefined behavior? :)

Comment: Undefined, no. Unspecified, yes. More reading here (http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/12684)

Comment: @Eli : Function call is indeed a sequence point (note `operator<<` is an overloaded function), so it doesn't invoke Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Alex : IMHO the article by Danny Kalev is flawed. Unspecified Behaviour doesn't guarantee same output (behavior) between different runs. Also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296523/is-implementation-defined-behavior-required-to-be-consistent-between-runs-in-c/) thread.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav - The article isn't flawed, but out of date. See the date "September 4, 1998" on the article. I believe a lot has changed in C++ after that.A guy involved with the standardization process of C++ wouldn't be dishing out crap !!

Comment: @DumbCoder : Hmm but I have also seen him calling `<iostream.h>` a deprecated header but it is not. I never said that the article was crap. One should not give reference to such an old article.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav - I believe you are again referring to old articles of Danny(http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14447), while you yourself mention not referring to old articles ?

Comment: @DumbCoder : My only point is that `<iostream.h>` should not be called deprecated because it was never a part of the Standard. Danny Kalev incorrectly calls it a deprecated header. This article was written after the release of C++98.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav - If I am correct the first standard was ratified in 1998, 19 years after it was written. Till 2002 most compilers supported both <iostream> and <iostream.h>. So it mayn't be totally wrong to call <iostream.h> deprecated. If you intend to intrepret the standards so strictly, then probably boost wouldn't have ever become a part of the new C++ standards.

Comment: @DumbCoder: and it hasn't (boost become part of the new standard). Only some libraries have affected the standard by providing a use case and sample implementation, but the standard has reworked most (if not all) of them, sometimes only in the underlying implementation, sometimes in the interface or the semantics.